# What is the meaning of t in this collision detection algorithm

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I am looking to implement a collision detection algorithm between a projectile and a wall of targets using JavaScript. Both the projectile and targets are circles. I have the code but I am not exactly sure how it works. I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain the calculations, particularly the calculation of t (why is it calculated the way it is).

The code allows the user to fire a projectile by click on the screen. It then calculates the angle between the projectile and mouse and uses this angle to calculate the trajectory of the projectile. The size of the trajectory is calculated for each potential target, using `dx` and `dy`, as well as the position of the target relative to the projectile. My question is concerned with the calculation of t and how this calculation works.

```
//angle is the angle (in radians) between the projectile and mouse click
var dx = Math.sin(angle); 
var dy = Math.cos(angle);
var t = dx * distToBubble.x + dy * distToBubble.y; //distToBubble stores 
// distance along the x an y axis between distToBubble and projectile
var ex = -t * dx + start.left
var ey = -t * dy + start.top
```

I use the parametric equations `ex` and `ey` as the coordinates of the collision between the projectile and target

Comment: This seems like more of a math question than a Javascript question

Comment: seems like the direct distance between the 2 points missing a sqrt though

Comment: Regarding the JavaScript: you have a couple of syntax errors (missing `=`s). Regarding the equations, [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1353565) was asked on [math.se] 4 years ago... noting that the equation came from [a book "Build a HTML 5 Game"](https://books.google.com/books?id=eAYvDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA56&ots=PnxAm41CPf&dq=var%20t%20%3D%20dx%20*%20distToBubble.x%20%2B%20dy%20*%20distToBubble.y%3B&pg=PA56#v=onepage&q=var%20t%20=%20dx%20*%20distToBubble.x%20+%20dy%20*%20distToBubble.y;&f=false).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry about the syntax errors, not sure how I missed that. Thank you for the reference

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it pertains to math, not programming, and is already answered on [math.se].

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I looked all over the Internet but couldn't find anything explaining t.